# Is there any FREE android mail client with Exchange Support?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, email, exchange

I am searching for a free Exchange mail client for Android 2.3+. Can anybody please suggest me one?

Comment: What's wrong with the stock client?  Without specifics this is a shopping rec at best (off-topic, see the [FAQ]).

Comment: Stock client is not working for my exchange mail id. It fails to connect to exchange server. My build is Android 2.3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) supports Exchange 2003/2007 via WebDAV. No support for Exchange 2010, unfortunately, since Microsoft removed WebDAV support in the newest version.

See the [official wiki page](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/wiki/K9MailAndExchange) for configuration instructions.